# Smooth box-shadow effect on div in css

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

How do i get box-shadow effect like the one below in css.
my div is like the one below but without the shadows.

[image]

Comment: Please add the code you're using, it's easier to help you edit what you have than write it from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to learn and see what you need is to use a website like the following:

http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

You can see what the different values do with the shadow and you can answer your own question.

And if you don't want to learn that, for some reason, and linking is not really an answer, I think this will reproduce your shadow:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
```

Comment: hanks. that was similar. but how can i lighten the shadow a bit...

Answer (score 3):

You do it by stacking box shadows.

https://jsfiddle.net/wb2hz0zc/

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>

.bg {
    padding:20px;
    background:#EEE;
}

.box {
    background: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.13) ,1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1) , -1px -2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05) ;
}
```

Comment: thanks. that was similar. but how can i lighten the shadow a bit...

Comment: Change opacity  like rgba(0,0,0,.03)